# Isn't POP3 Download and Keep similar to IMAP

Tags: email, networking, smtp, imap, pop3

I recently read about **POP3** and **IMAP**.. There I read that POP3 can either **download and delete** or **download and keep** . However, isn't download and keep somewhat similar to IMAP where you are keeping a copy of your messages in the mail server in place of a remote server on IMAP ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No.  With IMAP, changes that you make using any of your mail clients are synced by the server.  For example, if you mark a message as read using one of your mail clients, this change is synced by the server, so that all of your other mail clients show that the message is read.  This is not the case with POP3.